# Splitting array of days into months

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of daily requirements. The first element in the array represents a start date. I need to convert the daily requirements into an array of monthly requirements.

I've tried the following:

```js
const monthSize = [1, 2, 3];
const startDate = moment(1535328000000);
console.log(startDate);
const dailyReq = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0,0,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0.7228819444444444,0];

const result = dailyReq.map((e, i) => {
  return i % monthSize === 0 ? dailyReq.slice(i, i + monthSize) : null;
}).filter((e) => {
  return e;
});

console.log(result.map(g => g.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This gives an output of `[22, 20]`. What is expected is `[12, 20, 10]`

I know my calculations are incorrect, however, I am unable to figure it out

**EDIT**
I've updated the sample data to include an array with 436 elements which spans over two years. The problem I am facing now is I need to break this array into months and have an array of months that starts from the startDate. So the expected output is `[0, 0, 0, 0 ..., 0, 54]` which will include months from 2018 and 2019

Comment: What is `monthSize`? Can you explain in words what exactly the desired logic is for obtaining `12, 20, 10`? If `startDate` is not relevant, feel free to remove it for a [MCVE]

Comment: @CertainPerformance So I have a table that displays daily values. I have a switch to view weekly, monthly etc based on the daily values. Looking at the array and the start date I know that `[12, 20, 10]` are the values for each month, i.e. The month is March, the start date is the 15th day of that month. Therefore the value `12` is the sum of from day values 15 to the end of march which is 31.

Comment: I made a snippet for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply group by month, then get each value's length

```js
const dailyReq = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1];
const startDate = moment(1521072000000);
const monthly = [...dailyReq.reduce((a, b, i) => {
    if (i > 0) startDate.add(1, 'days');
    return b === 0 ? a : a.set(startDate.month(), (a.get(startDate.month()) || []).concat(b));
}, new Map).values()].map(e => e.length);

console.log(monthly);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```